# SOLR doing full copy replication when softcommit is not enabled in master

Tags: solr, lucene, solr4

Am using solr version 5.2.1 hosted on Linux OS. I have master & slave architecture . Where master used for indexing and slave used for searching the docs.  Since master is only used for indexing i haven't enabled softcommit on master node, but recently i figured that due this slave is doing fullcopy of replication most of the time in day.

Could anyone let me know why softcommit is important for replicating the data. I believe the replication happens on the segements available in the disk but softcommit shouldn't impact that. Could anyone let me know if the softcommit even matter for replication.

Thanks

Comment: A hard commit forces the changes to be persisted to disk - and this can cause index file merges (i.e. the same as an optimize). Are you sure this is not what's happening? (if all the files on the server has changed - i.e. the index has been completely rewritten - a full replication has to take place).

Comment: @MatsLindh Yes we do have hard commit in place but that doesn't change all the segment files during every hard commit right so this where am lost.  Even though there is no huge changes its doing the full copy of the index.  And do you know any method which i can huge to find out the difference in the segment files between master and slave?